# Saving a spatial index in QGIS API?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, spatial-index

I am trying to create a spatial index for some shapefiles using the Qgis API. I have followed the steps described in Nathan Woodrow's blog (https://nathanw.net/2013/01/04/using-a-qgis-spatial-index-to-speed-up-your-code/) and it works great:

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer(path, name, 'ogr')
idx = QgsSpatialIndex()
all_features = layer.getFeatures()
map(idx.insertFeature, all_features)
```

My problem is that I don't have any resulting file (.qix ? .sbn ? .sbx ?)

How can I save this spatial index so that future users of the shapefiles can benefit from it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to create a spatial index for all features in your layer, you could try using the following:

```
layer.dataProvider().createSpatialIndex()
```

This will create the `.qix` spatial index file.

---

**Edit:**

As mentioned by [Matthias Kuhn](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9839/matthias-kuhn) in his comments below, the [QgsSpatialIndex](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsSpatialIndex.html) class is only used temporarily as seen in the blog you linked to; whereas the [createSpatialIndex()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html#a2fcb9f703debaf73667643614802d3a6) function creates a spatial index on the datasource and results in a `qix` file for shapefiles.

Comment: I think it would be good to highlight the difference between a persistent (file-based) and temporary, runtime index (QgsSpatialIndex).

Comment: Thanks guys ! I could only find information about QgsSpatialIndex. createSpatialIndex is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Lauref - Awesome, glad it helped :)

Comment: After 4 tries to write something comprehensive in this comment, I have to surrender and admit that it would require more for something adequate. What I wanted to say is just that the information that QgsSpatialIndex is not persistent gives a lot of information already without any extra explanation.

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn - Thanks, I've edited the post to include a brief explanation as you mentioned ;)

Comment: I hope you don't mind my last edit ;)

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn - Ofcourse not! Not going to argue with a QGIS core developer =)

Comment: Feel free to rethink this position whenever you feel it's appropriate, I would never pretend to be impeccable.